# Creating a service out of controller logic in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I currently have a lot of repetitive logic that I need use of in many different controllers and I'm looking for a way to have a more DRY method of doing things.

For instance,  I currently have about 12 controllers using a lazyload function that is used in each one.  Anytime I want to tweak that function I've got to go through all 12 (not smart i know!)  This is what a common version will look like:

```
    $scope.number = user.channel_id;
    activityFactory.query({channelID: user.channel_id}, function(data){
      // the page number
      $scope.page=1;
      $scope.isInfinitScrollDisabled=false;
      // function for inifinite scroll
      $scope.getNextPage=function(){
        $scope.page++;
        $scope.isInfinitScrollDisabled=true;
        // query for the next page
        activityFactory.query({
          channelID: $scope.number,
          page: $scope.page
          }, function(data){
            $timeout(function(){
                      $scope.isInfinitScrollDisabled=false;
            },2000);
            $scope.activities.results = $scope.activities.results.concat(data.results);
        });
      };
       $scope.activities = data;
    });
```

As you can see without this function I would have a much cleaner and readable controller with a lot of the business logic moved out to a service. IE:

```
    activityFactory.query({channelID: user.channel_id}, function(data){
       $scope.activities = data;
    });
```

The issue is I'm not really sure how to move this into a reusable formate.  I just started with:

```
  .service('lazyLoaded', ['', function(){
      // the page number
      $scope.page=1;
      $scope.isInfinitScrollDisabled=false;
      // function for inifinite scroll
    var getNextPage = function(){
      $scope.page++;
      $scope.isInfinitScrollDisabled=true;
      // query for the next page
        activityFactory.query({
          channelID: $scope.number,
          page: $scope.page
          }, function(data){
            $timeout(function(){
                      $scope.isInfinitScrollDisabled=false;
            },2000);
            $scope.activities.results = $scope.activities.results.concat(data.results);
        });
      };
  }])
```

However I'm not sure if Im supposed to pass $scope in or how to handle different resources since not everything will be scope.activities or I may not need to pass channelID: scope.number as a parameter.  How is something like this structured?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass scope into a service. Instead, some of the scope variables you move into the factory can still be accessed from the scope of the controller:

```
.factory('LazyLoaded', function() {
    var lazy = {
        page: 1
    };

    lazy.someFunction = function() {
        console.log('method called');
    };

    return lazy;
})

.controller('MyController', function($scope, LazyLoaded){
    $scope.lazy = LazyLoaded;
    console.log($scope.lazy.page); // logs 1
    $scope.lazy.someFunction(); // logs 'method called'
})
```

Comment: So I assume I would still need to pass things like timeout etc into it?  I think I grasp most of what you're saying.  I guess what I'm saying is.  On the controller am I passing in the new $scope.activities and setting that up in the service as well.  Since the page will always start at 1 that makes sense, but for things like channelId or $scope.activities i'm a bit lost

Comment: It's kind of hard to discuss the business logic without seeing a demo.  What I would say is that, yes, you can write to the service as well as read from the controller, using either getter/setter methods or by accessing the properties directly.. at least if you set it up the way I demonstrated.

Comment: Fair enough.  Thanks for the help Marc.